# Extract Data with Header from HTML Table

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver

Here are some sample html. We want to extract Data from it and want to save in dataBase. 
What is the easiest and fastest way to extract data using Id, name or class except via parent.
I am using Selenium and C# for this purpose but i can't understand how to extract data from tags.
AS you can see there are no id and name to find tags.

```
<tr>
        <td height="87" valign="top">
            <table width="730" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td width="78" height="87" style="border-top-width: 1px;    border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                        <img src="LogoWebBill.gif" width="78" height="86">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <table width="651" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td height="22" style="border-top-width: 1px;border-left-width: 1px;    border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;border-right-width: 1px;border-right-style: solid;border-right-color: #CC0000;">
                                    <p align="center" class="FieldCaption">
                                        <strong><font size="2">LAHORE ELECTRIC SUPPLY COMPANY - ELECTRICITY CONSUMER BILL(MDI)</font></strong></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="18" style="border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: #CC0000; border-right-width: 1px;border-right-style: solid;border-right-color: #CC0000;">
                                    <div align="center">
                                        <p class="FieldCaption">
                                            http://www.lesco.gov.pk</p>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">
                                    <table width="651" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody><tr class="FieldCaption">
                                            <td width="248" height="19" style="border-top-width: 1px;   border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="left">
                                                    &nbsp;CUSTOMER I.D.
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="51" style="border-top-width: 1px;    border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    &nbsp;ED@</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="86" style="border-top-width: 1px;    border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    &nbsp;BILL MONTH</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="89" style="border-top-width: 1px;    border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    &nbsp;READING DATE</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="89" class="FieldCaption" style="border-top-width: 1px;   border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    &nbsp;ISSUE DATE</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="89" style="border-top-width: 1px;border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;border-right-width: 1px;border-right-style: solid;border-right-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    <font color="#0066ff">&nbsp;DUE DATE</font></div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="28" class="GeneralText" style="border-top-width: 1px;   border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="left">
                                                    &nbsp;2000125</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="GeneralText" style="border-top-width: 1px;   border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    &nbsp;1.0%</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="GeneralText" style="border-top-width: 1px;   border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    &nbsp;Oct 18</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="GeneralText" style="border-top-width: 1px;   border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    &nbsp;02 NOV 18</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="GeneralText" style="border-top-width: 1px;   border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    &nbsp;08 NOV 18</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="GeneralText" style="border-top-width: 1px;border-left-width: 1px;    border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #CC0000; border-left-color: #CC0000;border-right-width: 1px;border-right-style: solid;border-right-color: #CC0000;">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    &nbsp;23 11 2018</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                            </td></tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get the innerHTML / outerHTML of the Table and extract using HTML Parser**

Find the element which is identifiable and then get the inner html of the element to extract the html of it.

```
 string html = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img [@src='LogoWebBill.gif']/parent::td/following-sibling::td"").GetAttribute("innerHTML")
```

Then parse it with offline using HTML Parser ([Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/))

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var title = doc.DocumentNode
 .SelectNodes("//tbody/tr")
 .First()
 . InnerText;
// This returns LAHORE ELECTRIC SUPPLY COMPANY - ELECTRICITY CONSUMER BILL(MDI)
// Similarly find the header and rows data with loops
```